# Render different live template name in Phoenix LiveView

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

In a regular controller/view, let's say I have `AppWeb.ItemView`, and `AppWeb.ItemController`.  Let's say I have two different indexes, `:index` and `:index_funky`.  If I wanted to render `index.html.eex` for the `:index_funky` view, I could create a render function in `AppWeb.ItemView` with the head `render("index_funky.html", assigns)` and inside that do a `render("index.html", assigns)`.  That works fine:  I would get the data from `AppWeb.ItemController.index_funky` using the template from `AppWeb.ItemController.index`.

How can I do the same with a `LiveView`?  If I have `AppWeb.ItemLive.Index` and `AppWeb.ItemLive.IndexFunky`, how can I render `index.html.leex` for `AppWeb.ItemLive.IndexFunky`?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your reason behind it, but I would encourage you to look at [`handle_params`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#c:handle_params/3) if it helps your case.

Now, for your case, you can delegate to an existing view like this

```
defmodule AppWeb.ItemLive.IndexFunky do
  use AppWeb, :live_view

  def render(assigns) do
    Phoenix.View.render(AppWeb.ItemLive.Index, "index.html", assigns)
  end
end
```

[Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#module-collocating-templates)

Comment: As for reasoning, continuing with my fake example, `:index` would be all `Items`, whereas `:index_funky` is just `Items` that have the `funky` attribute.  Exact same attributes being displayed in a table, but just a subset of the data.  It's very duplicative to copy the template for several views, especially when I also want to display an `:index_groovy` and an `:index_nifty` as well.

Comment: @Brendon yeah, handle_params should do the trick, you can even just do a `live_path` link for :funky, :nifty, :groovy, and let the handle_params to assign the correct result to socket

Comment: take a look at this example where handle_params is used, https://elixirschool.com/blog/live-view-live-component/